# Duplicate item when saving certificate identities in the iOS Keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain, client-certificates

I'm trying to figure out what exactly means the status code `errSecDuplicateItem` for the `SecItemAdd` method when trying to add a certificate identity to the iOS keychain.

Reading the iOS documentation, it only says that this status code means the item is duplicated in the keychain, but what is the criteria to determine if an identity is a duplicate? Issuer name? Expiration date? Both?

If you read to the Mac OSX documentation, the discussion section for [a similar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCertificateAddToKeychain) method says the following:

> If the certificate has already been added to the specified keychain,
>   the function returns errSecDuplicateItem and does not add another copy
>   to the keychain. The function looks at the certificate data, not at
>   the certificate object, to determine whether the certificate is a
>   duplicate. It considers two certificates to be duplicates if they have
>   the same primary key attributes.

I know there is a difference, I'm trying to save the certificate identity in the keychain, and this discussion is for the `SecCertificateAddToKeychain` method which saves the certificate; but I believe there is a connection.

What's the meaning of `"primary keys attributes"`?

I tried adding the same identity twice and of course I get the `errSecDuplicateItem`, but I'm afraid that users may get an error if they want to update the certificate in someway I'm not considering.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove the dublicate certificates from the keychain value! error arises coz you are using same identity to save another certificates,try to change the identity name and then safe or either remove the old one!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the keychain's primary key attributes aren't documented. However, according to a [message from Ken McLeod](http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-cdsa/2010/Feb/msg00050.html), certificates are identified by their certificate type, issuer, and serial number. The keychain will refuse to accept more than one certificate that has the exact same values for these attributes.

Certificate authorities are required not to issue two certificates with the same serial number, so this error is unlikely to happen for your users. If you're generating certificates yourself, you must also make sure you do not accidentally reuse serials.